# How can I mix tags and boolean variables to execute/not execute a task?

Tags: ansible

Ansile 2.11

Say I have a task where I want to start a service only during a "new install" or an "update" of its corresponding application. IOW, I don't want it to start during an "uninstall" for example. However, I only want to do this when I'm installing this particular application by itself. When I'm installing it as part of a list of applications, I don't want to start the service since I have a separate role that starts ALL the services. I tried

In `defaults/main.yml`

```
---
web_service_only: false
```

In `tasks/main.yml`

```
---
- name: Start the service
  service:
    name: some_service
    state: started
  when: web_service_only
  tags:
  - new_install
  - update

- name: Stop the service
  service:
    name: some_service
    state: stopped
  tags: uninstall
```

I don't expect the "Start the service" task to execute when I simply do

```
$ ansible-playbook -i hosts my_host my-playbook.yml --tags new_install
```

because of the `web_service_only` variable set to `false`, however it does execute. What am I missing. How can I achieve what I want?

Comment: Check that your variable is not passed as a string instead of a boolean. And since Ansible pretty much casts everything back to a string at some point, the good practice is: `when: web_service_only | bool`